# How to open Firefox's "organize bookmarks" from Vimperator?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons, bookmarks, vimperator

Before using [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891/), I used [Xmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2410/) for organizing and synchronizing bookmarks between computers. Now I installed [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891/) and I can only bookmark a page from command mode with `:bmark`.

### How can I open Organize Bookmarks with [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891/)?

Besides disabling [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891/) and choosing it from the menu what else can I do? Before, I had <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> to open the organizer. Now, in [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891/), this shortcut doesn't work anymore, even after temporarily disabling [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891/) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>.

[image: Firefox Organize Bookmarks Screenshot]

---

### EDIT

After setting the main menu visible (with `:set go+=m` thanks to **[Hamish Downer](https://superuser.com/users/1630/hamish-downer)**), I saw the shortcut for opening the organize bookmarks dialog (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>). I recently switched to Ubuntu Linux and in this version of Firefox some keyboard shortcuts are different then in Windows (including the shortcut for opening organize bookmarks). Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch this using the `dialog` command:

```
:dialog bookmarks
```

Once you have typed `dialog` you should be shown a list of options that you can type. To find out more you could do

```
:help :dialog
```

Don't forget that you can always show the menu and select stuff the old way.

```
:set go+=m
```

`go` is short for `guioptions` and `m` is for menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my ignorance. I could have enabled myself the menu and see that the shortcut is different then in Windows instead of annoying people here on SU.

Comment: @Igor: no problem. It's always good to have the information available online for others to find.